# Play Store Developer Page

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-services

I've created a personal developer account for myself on Playstore, as I was about to publish my first app(free app, doesn't have in-app purchases), I saw a new policy change that will allow users to see developer's address, email and phone number. I've reached out to playstore support to get more information, but wasn't successful, they just provided me with the links to irrelevant articles. So my question is for the indie developers, what other options do we have? Is there a way to hide my personal information if my apps are free?

P.S. when I created developer account, playstore info said that my personal address, phone and email will be used for verification purposes only and it won't be displayed, but now they're changing policy which I believe takes effect after August 31st 2023.

Any guidance or advise is very appreciated.